# how to download files from aws s3 using a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have list of files in a bucket in aws s3, but  when i execute the aws cp command it gives me an error saying "unknown option".

my list

```
s3://<bucket>/cms/imagepool/5f84dc7234bf5.jpg
s3://<bucket>/cms/imagepool/5f84daa19b7df.jpg
s3://<bucket>/cms/imagepool/5f84dcb12f9c5.jpg
s3://<bucket>/cms/imagepool/5f84dcbf25d4e.jpg
```

My bash script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
aws s3 cp "${line}" ./
done <../links.txt
```

This is the error I get:
Unknown options: s3:///cms/imagepool/5f84daa19b7df.jpg

Does anybody know how to solve this issue.

Comment: The code is fine. Your real code and the list must be different then in the question.

Comment: it is the same, if i echo the cp command and execute in the console it works fine

Comment: I run your code, it works. As I can see, its not possible to get your error if your code is same as in the question.

Comment: Your error message shows `s3:///cms`, which is quite different from `s3://<bucket>/cms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out  the solution below worked(had to include the --no-cli-auto-prompt flag):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
aws s3 cp --no-cli-auto-prompt "${line}" ./

done <../links.txt
```